# Compare list element with a second unequal sized list element

Tags: python

I have two lists of unequal size and want to compare an element in new_list with an element in old_list.

```
new_list = [['<id>','<name>','<account_id>','<ip_address>'], ...]
old_list = [['<id>','<ip_address>'], ...]
```

I have a database where I want to track ip_address changes, so I get a old_list and if the ip_address is different in new_list for the same id, update the database.

```
for x in new_list:
    for y in old_list:
        if x[3] in y[0]:
            # update the DB
```

This seems to work, but looks as though it'll become pretty inefficient when the list grows.

new_list currently has 700 elements.
old_list currently has 600 elements.

When using the loop above, it brings back over 300,000.

Note: Some may not have an ip_address associated with it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the example. `x[3]` in this case would be a single character. Is `new_list` actually a list of lists?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with a large amount of data, dictionary lookups are faster than list lookups. If I understand correctly, you want to find records where `id` from new has a different IP address than the same `id` in old. Here is a solution for that:

```
new_list = [[1,'qwe',123,'1.1.1.1'],
            [2,'asd',234,'2.2.2.2'],
            [3,'zxc',345,'3.3.3.3']]

old_list = [[2,'2.2.2.2'],
            [3,'4.4.4.4'],
            [4,'5.5.5.5']]

# Map old IDs to old IP addresses, to be used for faster lookup than list
old_dict = dict(old_list)

for x in new_list:
    new_ip = x[3]
    new_id = x[0]
    if new_id in old_dict and old_dict[new_id] != new_ip:
        print(new_id, new_ip)
        # Update DB
```

Output is:

```
3 3.3.3.3
```

Because id 3 has IP address '3.3.3.3' in new_list, but '4.4.4.4' in old list.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping through the old_list every time. Create a list of all old IP and then check it with the new list.

**EX:**

```
old_ip_list = set(y[0] for y in old_list)
for x in new_list:
    if x[3] in old_ip_list:
        #Do Update+
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using dictionaries.

```
>>> old_dict = {'<id>':{'name':'<name>','account_id':'<account_id>','ip_address':'<ip_address>'}}
>>> new_dict = {'<id>':{'name':'<new_name>','account_id':'<new_account_id>','ip_address':'<new_ip_address>'}}
>>> old_dict['<id>'].update(new_dict['<id>'])
>>> old_dict
{'<id>': {'name': '<new_name>', 'account_id': '<new_account_id>', 'ip_address': '<new_ip_address>'}}
```

Or if you need to specifically capture the change of the ip address, dictionaries make it easy to efficiently make the comparison.

```
>>> old_dict['<id>']['ip_address'] == new_dict['<id>']['ip_address']
True
```

Dictionaries are also a preferred structure for information sets of varying length as it is easy to test if a key exists inside the dictionary before proceeding to the next operation.

```
>>> '<id>' in old_dict
True
>>> 'ip_address' in old_dict['<id>']
True
>>> 'test' in old_dict['<id>']
False
```

Dictionaries are also very compatible with json and dataframes making them an ideal choice for data analysis and APIs. The best part is that inspite of their usefulness, pyhton dictionaries are very efficient data structures.